# How can I set a global JSON options for ReadFromJsonAsync method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, razor, razor-pages

I have a web app project with .net core 6, and I'm trying to get some JSON data from another API I built. In that API, I'm returning JSON containing some Enums converted to strings. Then in my web app project, the `ReadFromJsonAsync` method would throw an exception because it couldn't convert those strings back to enums or something, so I could fix it by making JSON options for the `ReadFromJsonAsync` method like this:

```
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public AuthService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<ApiResult<LoginResponse>?> Login(LoginCommand command)
    {
        var result = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/login", command);
    
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Converters = {new JsonStringEnumConverter()},
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        };
        var content = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<LoginResponse>>(options);

        return content;
    }
}
```

This works, but the problem is that I'm going to use this method a lot throughout different classes, I can't write these options every time, so I want to apply these options globally.

I tried doing this in my `Program.cs` class but it doesn't work at all:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
});
```

How can I apply these options globally? so that I don't have to pass these options every time?

Comment: You could inject `IOptions<JsonOptions>` into the controller or action method (and then use `options.Value.JsonSerializerOptions`). Beyond the basic `HttpClient`, it's all out of the loop re the options that you've configured there and the dependency injection. It would be nice if there was some movement to improve that though.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean by out of the loop? what is out of the loop, and what should be improved? sorry, my English is not very well, I might misunderstand what you say. And how should I inject that `IOptions<JsonOptions>` in my `Program.cs` class? I added it to my class's constructor, but I don't know how to register that dependency in my `Program.cs`

Comment: It would be ideal if there was a way to apply those options globally, and not have to pass any `options` parameter to the `ReadFromJsonAsync` method. idk if it's possible.

Comment: My point was that `ReadFromJsonAsync` is an extension method on `HttpContent`. As such, no dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an answer to the question, but it might be helpful for some trying to (de)serialize the enum type from/to string without specifying the options each time.

Apply `JsonConverter` attribute to the enum type.

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Please use the answers function for actual answers only. Your non-answer may be flagged and deleted. This information should be a comment or an answer to a different question.

Comment: If enums declared in common library then using this attribute is an answer. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm injecting it directly like this, but I'm still curious to know if there's a way to apply these options globally without even passing the `options` parameter to the `ReadFromJsonAsync` method.

In my `program.cs` class:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() },
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
});
```

And I use it like this:

```
public class AuthService : IAuthService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _jsonOptions;

    public AuthService(HttpClient client, JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions)
    {
        _client = client;
        _jsonOptions = jsonOptions;
    }

    public async Task<ApiResult<LoginResponse>?> Login(LoginCommand command)
    {
        var result = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/auth/login", command);
        var content = await result.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<ApiResult<LoginResponse>>(_jsonOptions);
        return content;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to separately register the settings like this. `AddJsonOptions` is already registering `IOptions<JsonOptions> `. You can inject that.

Comment: I tried what you're saying, but it didn't work, for some reason, the `AddJsonOptions` doesn't work AT ALL, when I add it after the `AddRazorPages`, like this: `AddRazorPages().AddJsonOptions(options => ...)` And then I injected the `IOptions<JsonOptions>` into my class but it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: You mean `IOptions<JsonOptions>` isn't being injected?

Comment: It seems like it, but if I start my project, it doesn't throw an exception for not being able to resolve that dependency, it throws an exception about my returned API result, which it can't convert the strings back to enums, this exception: `JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to Common.Api.ApiStatusCode` the `ApiStatusCode` is the enum causing problem.

Comment: Did you pass the `JsonSerializerOptions` value from within `IOptions<JsonOptions>` to `ReadFromJsonAsync`? It's sounding like you didn't.

Comment: So you now have something like [this](https://pastebin.com/VqnUEgyM) and it's failing? Are you still adding the enum converter as in your question?

Comment: Yes, Exactly that. Yes both the converter and case insensitive property.

Comment: I'm puzzled then. It works fine when I test the same thing.

Comment: Then I'm most probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is, but the method that I posted as answer, kinda works fine. is there any downside to the way that I did it? is your method the right way to do it?

Comment: The only downside I see is that you're essentially setting up the same set of options twice.  Other than that, I think it's fine.